# Update AWS ECS service after ECR image being updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have ESC service with EC2 task running on an EC2 instance. The image in the EC2 task is from the ECR uri: for example: `688523422345.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/image`, I noticed that when I load this image into my EC2 task I just directly using the uri:`688523422345.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/image:latest`, because the image uri never changes and I just keep push image to update it.

However, when the image did updated on ECR, the task and service running on EC2 instance doesn't updating. I wondering why, and search on stack overflow, people told me that using `aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster name> --service <service name> --force-new-deployment` to force the service to re-deploy. However, I just got error on not enough memory left on the instance(seems the re-deployment will create new task and it keep taking more memories, not a good solution).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of your  [Deployment configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html#sd-deploymentconfiguration) and the parameters:

- maximumPercent
- minimumHealthyPercent

By default `minimumHealthyPercent` is 100% which means that replacement operation will first attempt to run new tasks, before terminating old ones, potentially resulting in out of memory error. You can set it up to `minimumHealthyPercent` to 0 and `maximumPercent` to 100 as to force termination of existing tasks first, before creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, after tried a lot. I find out is because the EC2 instance already stored all the information from a task(even if deleted task, the instance is still running with the image). The right way to do it is to re-start the instance.

I used aws-cli: `aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids <instance_id>`

It worked!